# MAXIMA - Resolve an overdetermined system using least squares estimate

Tags: matrix, system, equation, least-squares, maxima

I am desperately trying to resolve an overdetermined system using Maxima and the lsquares_estimate function.

The system is described by this matrix equation :
M.D = I

Here is M :

```
M:matrix([19.707,0.06700000000000017,0,0,0,0,0,0,19.707-Phi01_8,0,0,0],
[0,0,-0.2690000000000019,0.7359999999999971,0,0,0,0,0,19.371-Phi01_8,0,0],
[-0.067234,-24.562234,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi12_8-0.067234,0,0,0],
[0,0,-1.753,3.741,0,0,0,0,0,22.742-Phi12_8,0,0],
[-0.26894,1.75226,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi23_8-0.26894,0,0,0],   
[0,0,92.99119999999999,14.967,0,0,0,0,0,90.97-Phi23_8,0,0],
[-0.73571,3.74149,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi34_8-0.73571,0,0,0],
[0,0,-14.9658,-655.2429999999999,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi34_8-19.443,0,0],
[-1.8393,9.3537,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi45_8-1.8393,0,0,0],
[0,0,-37.415,361.892,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi45_8-48.608,0,0],
[-8.6658,5.6092,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi56_8-8.6658,0,0,0],
[0,0,-22.437,166.598,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi56_8-36.712,0,0],
[-5.1995,3.3655,0,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi67_8-5.1995,0,0,0],
[0,0,-13.462,99.953,0,0,0,0,0,-Phi67_8-22.027,0,0])
```

Here is D :

```
D:matrix([0.0499998750003125],
[0.0399993670651863],
[0.009999946119925522],
[0.001250003764581481],
[4.999947987060861*10^-4],
[1.000099826698366*10^-4],
[1.666560996027836*10^-4],
[0.00499998750003125],
[D8],[D9],[D10],[D11])
```

And here is I :

```
I:matrix([1],[0],[-1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[-1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0])
```

The system has 14 equations and 9 variables. (D8,D9,Phi01,Phi12,Phi23,Phi34,Phi45,Phi56,Phi67)
I want to get a least squares estimate of those variables. I am using the "lsquares_estimates" function. In order to give the right input to the function, I merge the matrix equation into one matrix. This is how i call the lsquares_estimates function :

```
D0:D[1][1]$
D1:D[2][1]$
D2:D[3][1]$
D3:D[4][1]$
D4:D[5][1]$
D5:D[6][1]$
D6:D[7][1]$
D7:D[8][1]$
D8:D[9][1]$
D9:D[10][1]$
D10:D[11][1]$
D11:D[12][1]$

C:addcol(M,I);
resultat:lsquares_estimates(C,
[c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,Ie],
Ie=c0*D0+c1*D1+c2*D2+c3*D3+c4*D4+c5*D5+c6*D6+c7*D7+c8*D8+c9*D9+c10*D10+c11*D11,
[Phi01_8,Phi12_8,Phi23_8,Phi34_8,Phi45_8,Phi56_8,Phi67_8,D8,D9]);
```

Obviously, Maxima is not able to resolve this system... It keeps running for a very longtime, and sometimes, here is the error i get :

```
Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
-: ((MTIMES SIMP) -0.14285714285714285
 ((MPLUS SIMP)
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) 0.01197250577547404
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 ((MPLUS SIMP) 19.707 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi01_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) 19.707 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi01_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.014164494697229801
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.067234 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi12_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.067234 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi12_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.056642324551059296
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.26894 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi23_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.26894 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi23_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.11287182384424398
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.73571 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi34_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.73571 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi34_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -0.28217730962955834
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -1.8393 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi45_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -1.8393 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi45_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) 0.2089244670356651
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -8.6658 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi56_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -8.6658 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi56_8|)))
  ((MTIMES SIMP)
   ((MPLUS SIMP) 0.12535648020624035
    ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0
     ((MPLUS SIMP) -5.1995 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi67_8|))))
   ((MPLUS SIMP) -5.1995 ((MTIMES SIMP) -1.0 |$Phi67_8|))))) is not a number
Automatically continuing.
To enable the Lisp debugger set *debugger-hook* to nil.
```

Am I using lsquares_estimates the wrong way ? When i reduce the number of equations to match the number of variables, I can get a result, but i would like an accurate result using all my equations.

Any help would be really appreciated... 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lsquares_estimates` constructs a mean square error expression and then tries to solve it exactly, and then approximately, if solving it exactly doesn't yield a result. Not sure where things are going wrong there.

But anyway you can jump directly to `lsquares_estimates_approximate`. Try this:

```
e1 : M.D - I;
my_mse : transpose(e1) . e1;
load (lsquares);
lsquares_estimates_approximate (my_mse, [Phi01_8, Phi12_8, Phi23_8, 
    Phi34_8, Phi45_8, Phi56_8, Phi67_8, D8, D9], tol=1e-4);
```

Note that `my_mse` is the squared norm of the error.

With these inputs I get:

```
[[Phi01_8 = 22.70059866292853,Phi12_8 = -4.329661712144546,
  Phi23_8 = -17.40507905561839,Phi34_8 = -34.32504757490423,
  Phi45_8 = -85.85849926978096,Phi56_8 = 54.09091751735507,
  Phi67_8 = 32.46719922407783,D8 = -0.003346473781793617,
  D9 = 2.1359057759474724E-5]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The output are not the values I was expecting, there might be something wrong with my system. But still, I will now try to use this function.

Comment: Try to make `tol` a smaller value (e.g. try 1e-6 and/or 1e-8). Sometimes that changes the results.

Comment: @lilian Also try to substitute the solution into `my_mse` and verify that it's a number close to zero. E.g. `subst(my_soln[1], my_mse);` where `my_soln` is the result returned by `lsquares_estimates_approximate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's pretty weird because when I remove some equations from my system, I get a more accurate result. For example when substituting the solution, the squared norm of the error can go from 3E-2 to 5E-4 ...  There must be something wrong with my system.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong, that's to be expected. The error is a sum of terms e1^2 + e2^2 + e3^2 + ... . If you remove some of them, you'll get a smaller sum.

Comment: There is still something I don't understand. I now have 8 equations and 6 unknowns. When using these 8 equations, lsquares_estimates does not stop calculating and never gives a solution. When removing two of those equations, it gives the perfect result... But I need to use all of my equations... lsquares_estimates_approximate gives a solution in both cases, but always a wrong one. Is there any way to improve the approximation?

Comment: "lsquares_estimates does not stop calculating": well, it is trying to find an exact result and it is not able. That's a limitation of the function to solve a system of equations. Sorry about that. "lsquares_estimates_approximate gives a solution in both cases, but always a wrong one." In what sense is it wrong? The residual error is small. If you need to get a smaller error, make `tol` smaller. Also, I notice that some of the elements of the solution are much bigger than others. This can make the determination of smaller elements less accurate. Perhaps you can rescale the equations somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
"In what sense is it wrong?"
It is not the expected solution regarding the "physics" behind the equation (for example, every D values should be strictly positive). lsquares_estimates gives the right solution when giving as much equations as unknowns, but can't deal with an overdetermined system..
I tried making tol as small as possible, but it doesn't give me any more accurate result. I will try to rescale the equations, it can be a good idea!

Comment: If some values should be strictly positive, then you'll need to solve a constrained minimization problem. I can try to help with that if you want to go down that road. "I tried making tol as small as possible, but it doesn't give me any more accurate result." -- I don't know what you mean by this. If tol is smaller, then the sum of squares of errors is smaller, i.e. you're closer to a solution -- this is the definition of "least squares". If you intend some other criterion, then you must formulate and solve a different problem (e.g. a constrained minimization problem).

Comment: By "accurate result", I meant a solution that is close to the one expected regarding the physics behind the system. Making tol smaller at a certain point is not making the sum of squares of errors smaller by the way... 
This system of equations is obtained from simulation of an electrical circuit, and using kirchoff's laws. D are values of electrical conductances (1/R). I expect my system to give the D values I used with my simulation (which are the "correct values" I am talking about). I get these values using lsquares_estimates (but only with a limited number of equations).

Comment: It could be interesting to add some other criterion (such as D > 0). Is it possible ? Maybe i will get better results.

Comment: What SSE value are you getting from lsquares_estimates_approximate? What value do you get if you substitute what you consider the correct values into the expression for the SSE? What are the values for the parameters which you consider correct? Thanks for the information.

Comment: From lsquares_estimates_approximate, i get a SSE value of `0.157`. If i substitute what i consider the correct values, i get `5.850976755608908*10^-9`... Maybe i should add the condition `D>0`, how can I do that ? 
The values I consider correct are : `expected:[Phi01_8 = 37.717368, Phi12_8 = 7.203531, Phi23_8 = 5.6027463, Phi34_8 = -0.94668253, Phi45_8 = -0.4733412, Phi56_8 = -2.462832, Phi67_8 = -6.1570797, D8 = 0.0166666, D9 = 0.022222, D10 = 0.03333333, D11 = 0.025];`


(It's not the exact same system as before but the problem is the same, tell me if you need the whole system)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, I will try to take a look at it within the next few days. What is the whole system for which `expected` is the correct result?

Comment: @lilian When I substitute `expected` into `my_mse`, I get 5.847992... while `lsquares_estimates_approximate` returns a solution which MSE = 0.009095.... I see `expected` includes variables (D10, D11) which aren't present in `my_mse`. As you say, it's the solution for a related but different equation. In general solutions are pretty closely tied to the equations; unless you have specific information about your problem, there's no reason to expect that the solution for one equation will work in another. At this point my only guess is that you are not solving the problem you really want to solve.

Comment: This is normal. The expected vector and mse value I gave you are not for the system I sent earlier. I will send you the correct one